# How to use get_the_category() and display the categories in menu order?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the below code to show the categories of the current post (excluding cat id 14). Issue is they're not in the order I want. I need them to display in menu order.. Is this possible?

```
  $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $output = $category->cat_name;
        if($category->cat_ID !== 14){
            echo $output;
        }
    }
```

Comment: something like :  `$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'category', array( 'orderby' => 'menu_order' , 'exclude' => array(14)));` might work? haven't testet.

Comment: 'orderby' => 'menu_order' didn't work for some reason

Comment: try `term_order` instead then?

Comment: Yeah just did, that worked. Thanks mate

Comment: gonna post it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After discussion in comments :

`get_the_category()` doesn't accept orderby clauses, so use `wp_get_post_terms()` instead.

Use it like this

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'category', array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' , 'exclude' => array(14)));
```

This way the term with ID 14 is excluded as well.